# DataMatrix vs GS1 DataMatrix

Tags: matrix, scanning, datamatrix, gs1-datamatrix

I've been trying to find out if there is a difference between the way information is stored in DataMatrix vs GS1 DataMatrix forms.  I'm wondering if a regular DataMatrix scanner can scan a GS1 DataMatrix code or not.  Any help on this subject would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full specification for GS1 DataMatrix is at http://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_DataMatrix_Introduction_and_technical_overview.pdf

I can't find anything in it which would indicate any incompatibility.

Indeed, it specifically says that it uses the normal DataMatrix rules.  The GS1 part refers to the data which is encoded.

So, yes, a regular scanner will be able to read a GS1 DataMatrix barcode.

Comment: great, that's exactly the way I understood it.  Thank you!